# weka.attributeSelection.InfoGainAttributeEval is too slow. Any ideas on how to speed it up?

Tags: java, weka

I'm developing an application where attributes need to be ranked for a specific set of instances dynamically on the fly. Right now, I'm using information gain to rank attributes but its a little too slow.

Note: The dataset I'm using has about 50,000 attributes.

Code I'm running,

```
AttributeSelection attsel = new AttributeSelection();
InfoGainAttributeEval eval = new InfoGainAttributeEval();
Ranker search = new Ranker();
attsel.setEvaluator(eval);
attsel.setSearch(search);
double[][] attrRanks = new double[data.numAttributes()][2];
try {
    attsel.SelectAttributes(data);
    attrRanks = attsel.rankedAttributes();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This might be a little excessive, but if you have the Weka Source, you could try profiling to work out where the computational time is being eaten up, and determine where to go from there.  50,000 attributes is a lot of data!

Comment: I actually did try. Turns out the memory intensive part was the attribute selection class. Using just the InfoGainAttributeEval class and manually generating a list of attributes is much faster. Thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the ranking is actually quite quick but the process of creating ~30,000 - 40,000 Attribute Objects takes a while. I removed that part of code and it started working fine. 
New Code

```
GainRatioAttributeEval eval = new GainRatioAttributeEval();
try{
    eval.buildEvaluator(data);
} catch(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("Couldn't evaluate gain ratio", e);
}
Double infogain = Double.MIN_VALUE;
ObjectNode objNode;
int k, i;
double[][] ig = new double[data.numAttributes()][2];
for(int j=0;j<data.numAttributes();j++){
    try {
        ig[j][0] = j;
        ig[j][1] = eval.evaluateAttribute(j);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        LOGGER.error("Couldn't evaluate gain ratio for empty entrezIds.",e);
    }
}
Arrays.sort(ig, new Comparator<double[]>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (o1[1] > o2[1]) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1[1] < o2[1]) {
                return 1;
            }
                    return 0;
    }
});
//Ig is sorted array.
```